# Where to look into for the Safari browser error console in IPad which is using IOS 7?

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios7

I have an application which is running on Safari in IPad(IOS 7) . When i click on one of the button it is showing some JS error. Where exactly i need to into for the script error console? I don't see any error console in safari when it is running on IPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get a Mac computer
2. Open Safari on Mac
3. Enable the Develop menu https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html
4. Using a cable, connect your iPad to the Mac
5. On the iPad enable Web Inspector. Settings > Safari > Advanced (scroll down to the bottom to see it) > Web Inspector (set to On)
6. On the iPad open the Web application
7. On the Mac open the Develop menu. When it drops down, you will see your iPad shown in the menu as a separate menu item. That menu item should have a submenu showing Web pages/applications currently opened on your iPad. Choose your Web application.
8. You get your application in the Development Console, so do whatever you can (Safari Development tools are pretty weird, but, still, better something than nothing :) )

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I don't have mac machine with me, instead i have installed Safari web browser on  Windows 7. Is the procedure you mentioned same for Windows 7 as well? or will it differ?

Comment: Huh, never gave it a try with the Windows version of Safari... If you get any experience with it, let us know, please :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can see the console on Mac's Safari when your iPad is connected to it.