# How to check the console in React Native for Web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I am just getting started learning 'React Native for Web' one week ago. When I learn 'React', it is pretty easy to check the console statement. Just open the developer tool and check the console pannel and then I can check the console easily.
However, when I start learning 'React Native for Web', I am not sure how to check the console.
What I did so far, 1) Open Xcode Simulator and press command+d and click 'Debud remote JS' however, I cannot check any console statement such as hi.
2)Open Safari and then click Develop --> open simulator. It also doesn't show any console....

Could you help me out with it? How to check the console? I checked the apple official video but they only show how to debug except the console...

It would be really appreciate for your help!

Comment: You want to check the console when running your web app in iOS safari. Am I right?

Comment: @Mohammad yeah you`re right! I am still waiting for the answer..

Comment: This one may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991905/7178860